# str object has no attribute str

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to implement a function which does the following:

1. Iterates through a column - df['input_str'] which contains strings such as 'disvt', disr5', 'disvt_r1', 'disr5/r6'
2. If a string contains the pattern, then using .extract(), extract the pattern and append it to a list.
3. If the list has no length, return 0.
4. Otherwise connect the items in the list with _

The goal is to create a new column that contains the matches to the patterns provided, i.e vt, r5, vt_r1, r5/r6.

Input Dataframe

```
col1   col2  col3  col4   input_str    
  a      .     .     .       disvt          
  b      .     .     .       disr5          
  c      .     .     .       disvt_r1        
  d      .     .     .       disr5/r6
```

```
def parse_info(input_str):
    patterns = ["r\d{1}", "vt", "v\d{2}", "v\d{1}"]
    new_list = []
    for pattern in patterns:
        if input_str.contains(pattern):
            new_list.append(input_str.extract(pat=pattern, expand=False))
    if len(new_list) == 0:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return "_".join(new_list)
```

Applying the function to create a new column:

```
df["new_column"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: x(df["input_str"]), axis=1
)
```

Desired output:

```
input_str    new_column
disvt           vt
disr5           r5
disvt_r1        vt_r1
r5/r6           r5_r6
```

This returns the following error: `str' object has no attribute contains

When I change .contains to .str.contains() I now get 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

I am a bit stuck at this point and not sure the best way to resolve these problems.

Comment: I think your second part of the code is wrong ?

Comment: patterns is supposed to have regex patterns, apologies for the ambiguity there. I have tried if pattern in input_str, which resolves the issue there, however the same problem appears with .extract()

Comment: Can you post a working example? We don't know what `input_str` is. You talk like its a regular python string but you seem to be using `panda` string methods against it. There is also a `df["new_column"]...` section that seems completely unrelated to the function.

Comment: @tdelaney - just added more information.

Comment: @user see my answer but you need to fix your regex patterns in order to get your desired output.

Comment: @user please accept one of the answers as solution by clicking the checkmark next to my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

EDIT (after updated question with input and expected output):

You can simply use `str.extract()`, but you need to fix your regex patterns. The key thing is to `join` the different patterns into a string separated by the or operator `|` and include inside of a capture group between two parentheses:

```
patterns = ["r\d{1}", "vt", "v\d{2}", "v\d{1}"]
df['new_column'] = df['input_str'].str.extract('(' + '|'.join(patterns) + ')')
df
Out[1]: 
  col1 col2 col3 col4 input_str new_column
0    a    .    .    .     disvt         vt
1    b    .    .    .     disr5         r5
2    c    .    .    .  disvt_r1         vt
3    d    .    .    .  disr5/r6         r5
```

The method `str.contains` is only for a `pandas.Series`. You should use `in` for a normal string as follows:

```
if input_str in pattern:
```

instead of

```
if input_str.contains(pattern):
```

Likewise, the method `str.extract` is only for a `pandas.Series`. You can try `re.match`, `re.findall`, list comprehension or other alternatives that work on normal python strings.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a list of patterns, you can use a single pattern using [str.findall](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) and join the results using [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

Pattern:

```
v(?:t|\d{1,2})|r\d
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LYUe9L/1)

For example

```
import pandas as pd

items= [
    "disvt",
    "disr5",
    "disvt_r1",
    "disr5/r6"
]

df = pd.DataFrame(items, columns=["input_str"])

df['new_column'] = df['input_str'].str.findall(r"v(?:t|\d{1,2})|r\d").apply('_'.join)
print(df)
```

Output

```
  input_str new_column
0     disvt         vt
1     disr5         r5
2  disvt_r1      vt_r1
3  disr5/r6      r5_r6
```